# Multiple divs horizontally on a container div

Tags: css, html

I want to make a div with multiple divs located at the bottom of the main div and that all divs that I add show horizontally

Example

```
------------------------
|                      |
|   Main Div           |
|                      |
|                      |
|-----|-----|          |
| div | div |          |
|----------------------|
```

I already have this code but it doesn't show the child divs at bottom

```
<style>
.spectrumcontainer{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 400px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    /*margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;*/
    /*padding: 0px;
    /*text-align: left;
    vertical-align: bottom;*/
    position: relative;
    /*float: none;*/
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.redbar{
    width: 35px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #ff0000; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 50%, #e50000 51%, #aa0000 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#ff0000), color-stop(50%,#ff0000), color-stop(51%,#e50000), color-stop(100%,#aa0000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 50%,#e50000 51%,#aa0000 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 50%,#e50000 51%,#aa0000 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 50%,#e50000 51%,#aa0000 100%); /* IE10+ */
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;

}
.orangebar{
    width: 35px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #ff7f00; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ff7f00 0%, #fc8600 50%, #e26200 51%, #bf5c00 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#ff7f00), color-stop(50%,#fc8600), color-stop(51%,#e26200), color-stop(100%,#bf5c00)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ff7f00 0%,#fc8600 50%,#e26200 51%,#bf5c00 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ff7f00 0%,#fc8600 50%,#e26200 51%,#bf5c00 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ff7f00 0%,#fc8600 50%,#e26200 51%,#bf5c00 100%); /* IE10+ */
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<div class="spectrumcontainer">
    <div class="redbar"></div>
    <div class="orangebar"></div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't works properly.

Here is the live example

http://jsfiddle.net/kelelehead/KQwnp/

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/KQwnp/2/?

Comment: this is `display`- and `vert.align`-ed http://jsfiddle.net/KQwnp/6/

Comment: The idea is to make a music spectrum and when I press that div it will grow (height) to UP, so if I use it like your example setting TOP:385 when I click the bar it grows to down instead up like this http://jsfiddle.net/kelelehead/TKKmA/

Answer (score 1):

I know a solution if you use divs with fixed heights.

html code:

```
<body>
<div class="main">
    <div class="bottom">
        div #1
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        div #2
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        div#3
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.main{
   background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}

.bottom{
    position: relative;
    top:100px;
    left:0px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
```

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/aleruar/8gyH8/

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use an additional div for containing the colored divs.

```
    <html>
<head>

<style>
.spectrumcontainer{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    /*margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;*/
    /*padding: 0px;
    /*text-align: left;
    vertical-align: bottom;*/
    position: relative;
    /*float: none;*/
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display:table;
}

.barContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 95%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
    margin: auto;
    background:#ddd;

    }
.redbar{
    background: #ff0000; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 50%, #e50000 51%, #aa0000 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#ff0000), color-stop(50%,#ff0000), color-stop(51%,#e50000), color-stop(100%,#aa0000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 50%,#e50000 51%,#aa0000 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 50%,#e50000 51%,#aa0000 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 50%,#e50000 51%,#aa0000 100%); /* IE10+ */
    float: left;
    width: 35px;
    height: 15px;


}
.orangebar{
    background: #ff7f00; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ff7f00 0%, #fc8600 50%, #e26200 51%, #bf5c00 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#ff7f00), color-stop(50%,#fc8600), color-stop(51%,#e26200), color-stop(100%,#bf5c00)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ff7f00 0%,#fc8600 50%,#e26200 51%,#bf5c00 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ff7f00 0%,#fc8600 50%,#e26200 51%,#bf5c00 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ff7f00 0%,#fc8600 50%,#e26200 51%,#bf5c00 100%); /* IE10+ */
    float: left;
    width: 35px;
    height: 15px;   
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="spectrumcontainer">
        <div class="barContainer">
            <div class="redbar"></div>
            <div class="orangebar"></div>
            <div class="redbar"></div>
            <div class="orangebar"></div>
            <div class="redbar"></div>
            <div class="orangebar"></div>
            <div class="redbar"></div>
            <div class="orangebar"></div>
        </div>
</div>


</body>
```

See the example in the following fiddle:

```
   http://jsfiddle.net/DD75W/
```

.barContainer top % will allow you to have a percentage height relational to the base div, allowing you to control the vertical position.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer in fact it works like charm, the idea is to make a music spectrum, when click any bar it gonna grows(height) with Jquery, I already make a test with a function... but when I click the red one the orange bar change its position to up with the another bar... so I need that the orange bar stays below check this example http://jsfiddle.net/kelelehead/DD75W/3/

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating DIVs dynamically on the bottom or even you need to have a lot of them I think a better approach is to create another container in the bottom with `position:absolute` as Mauro Laurent says.

```
.containerBottom {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:200px;
}
```

You can see an example in the fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/rafakol/SRVL7/1](http://jsfiddle.net/rafakol/SRVL7/1/)

If you add new DIVs you won´t need to change the CSS.

Hope it helps.